# Mixed Hodge structure cohomology of fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, mixed-hodge-structure

Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety. From Deligne's work, we know that the have a Mixed Hodge structure over its (rational) compactly supported cohomology $H^{*}_c(X,\mathbb{Q})$. With this, one can define the Euler-Hodge polynomial $$E(X,x,y)=\sum_{p,q}e_{p,q}x^py^q$$ where $$e_{p,q}=\sum_i (-1)^{i} dim Gr^W_{p+q} Gr_p^F H^i_c(X,\mathbb{Q}) $$.

Let us suppose we have another complex smooth algebraic variety $P$ with an algebraic  map $f:P \to X$ which is a fiber bundle with fiber $F$. I would like to know if there is any result that ensures us that $$E(X,x,y)E(F,x,y)=E(P,x,y).$$

This should somehow be thought of as a generalization of the similar equation which is true for Euler characteristic.

Comment: If it's a Zariski fibre-bundle, then it's true. You can use the fact that the $E$-polynomial only depends on the class in the Grothendieck ring of varieties.

Comment: If it just a fibre bundle in the etale topology? Can we still say it's true?

Comment: I don't know. I remember discussing it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472329/topology-of-fiber-bundles/3473029#3473029 but we couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: If that could help I'm looking for a statement with both $X,P$ assumed to be affine. But thank you for the reference and the other answer!

Comment: @Tommaso, perhaps I'm being silly but isn't the squaring map from punctured affine line to itself a counterexample if u relax the Zar loc trivial condition to étale loc triv?

Comment: Actually you are totally right: E polynomial of the punctured affine line is $xy-1$ so one would get a contradiction. I 've to admit I really believed it was true: I don't know if putting some connectedness hypothesis on the fiber works could be useful or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\pi_1(X)=0$, or more generally if the fundamental group of $X$ acts trivially on the compact support cohomology of the fiber, this is true because of the Leray spectral sequence. Otherwise it is almost never true (a simple counterexample was given by EBz in the comments: the squaring map $\mathbb G_m \to \mathbb G_m$).

Comment: Is there like an intuitive way of see why this should fall? Or like a geometric explanation? I thought this was true also because of Katz theorem which relates E polynomial to number of points over finite fields. So connectedness hypothesis would not be useful at all?

Comment: No, connectedness wouldn't help, either, though examples become more complicated. You may for example think of the projection from the Legendre family of elliptic curves down to $\mathbb P^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$.

Comment: Okok really thank you for the counterexamples :)

Comment: What if $E(F, x, y)=1$?

Comment: @virkkunen This happens only if $F$ is a point, which is not so interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There has been much research on computing $E$-polynomials of character varieties.  You can find a lot of general theory by reading those papers (just do a search for [key words](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=%22character%20variety%22%20%22E-polynomial%22)).

In particular, the theorem you want is Proposition 2.1 here:

*[Hodge polynomials of the SL(2,C)-character variety of an elliptic curve with two marked points](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4914)* by Marina Logares, Vicente Muñoz.

I quote:

> Suppose that $B$ is connected and $\pi : Z \longrightarrow B$
> is an algebraic fibre bundle with fibre $F$ (not necessarily locally trivial in the Zariski topology) and that the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $H^∗_c(F)$ is trivial. Suppose that $Z, F, B$ are smooth. Then $e(Z) = e(F)e(B).$
>
> The hypotheses hold in particular in the following cases:
>
> - $B$ is irreducible and $\pi$ is locally trivial in the Zariski topology.
> - $\pi$ is a principal $G$-bundle with $G$ a connected algebraic group.

Comment: The result is true without assuming that the spaces are smooth. It follows from the Leray spectral sequence for compact support cohomology.